# How to track a 6km long road. How to dissolve markers

Tags: tracking

I need to track a 6km long road. Its 4k footage made by a drone and I want to stabalize the footage along the way. When I stabalize and play the footage, and one tracker goes off the screen (because it has reached its end of the frame), the screen 'jumps' tot the next tracker/marker..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have 4k footage filed by a drone. it needs to be stabalized. The road is 6km long. How can I stabalize a 6km long road...